# How would I remove all the white from this image? I just want the image to be the red parts

Tags: adobe-photoshop, transparency, background-removal

[image]

The question pretty much stated it all, I want the red parts for transparency and all the white removed from this fingerprint image.

Comment: Use **Select > Color Range...** or channels. Anyway this should be easy enough to Google from

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove neutral background in photoshop?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/62676/how-to-remove-neutral-background-in-photoshop)

Answer (score 34):

- Double click your background layer in the layer pallet (to make it into a standard layer)
- Choose `Selection -> Color Range`
- Click in the white area of the image
- Bring the fuzziness up around 90
  [image]
- Click OK
- Hit <kbd>DELETE</kbd> and there you go!

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 15):

- <kbd>Ctrl/Command</kbd>+Click the green channel thumbnail in the **Channels Panel**
- Hold down the <kbd>Option/Alt</kbd> key and...
- Click the `New Layer Mask` button at the bottom of the **Layers Panel**
- Save....

Comment: This makes my red fingerprint lose color and become whiter (become transparent)

Comment: Then you aren't following the steps properly, Shayan.

Comment: Had the same problem with a different image using this technique.

Answer (score 5):

3 ways to do this:

Use Magic Erase Tool in Photoshop and adjust the Tolerance (Erase Range).

Or

Magic Wand Tool

Or

1. Go to Select option form the menu
2. Click "Load Selection"
3. Again go to Select option from the menu click "Color Range"
4. Select your image's white area with the help of color picker
5. Delete the selected area.

Answer (score 4):

..and now its even easier! In Gimp 2.8 simply click Color -> Color to Alpha.

Comment: Why the down-vote? This gives the same solution in the end, in shorter steps.

Comment: I guess it's because the OP is tagged as "Photoshop"

Answer (score 2):

My 2 cents.

1. Take your image (A) and choose a layer that is the most contrasted one. In this case green wil do (B).
2. In case you need it, slide the levels so you have a pure black and pure white on the center part of the colors. Do not over do this or you will losse detail on the aliasing your image already has (C).
3. Copy this.
4. Make a new layer of the color you need and make a new layer mask, and paste your image there. You probably need to invert it (D).
5. Ready. The image has the exactly same detail of the previous one and it has a pure colour, no halos or saw edges. (E).

[image]

Actually it is almost the same Scott, posted, but with some more detail.

Answer (score 1):

To completely remove all white from the image without losing any gradation from other colors (as will happen with the other methods presented here), do as follows:

1. Duplicate the image.
2. Set its color mode to multichannel.
3. Remove all channels but the channel with the most contrast - usually G, but in the OP's image it would be R.
4. In the original image, load selection, select the other image's channel.
5. Hit Delete, done. (You might need to invert the selection first.)

Comment: If I set `Image > Mode > Multichannel` I will only have Cyan, Magenta and Yellow, what do you mean click channel G or R on step 3? Also, Multichanel flattens the image, so I can't do this on layers, how can I bring the selection from second image to this image

Answer (score 0):

Remove all the white in the Image
Click the padlock icon on the background to unlock the layer
Right-click the layer name and choose "Blending Options"
At the bottom part of the dialog, you will see 2 sets of sliders "Blend if" sliders. On the upper set of sliders (this layer) drag the white slider towards the left - this will have the effect of removing all the pixels that fall outside the sliders.
When you are satisfied, create a new stamp layer of this -(Create a new empty layer and Shift-Ctrl-Alt-E)

Answer (score -1):

Trace in Illustrator > Save as PNG

Comment: That's one way sure, but it's a leap to assume that Zack has Illustrator available

Answer (score -2):

Expanding on [this](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/36460/124986) answer:

If you have Adobe Illustrator handy:

Window <kbd>></kbd> Image Trace <kbd>></kbd> Advanced

[image: Image Trace]

The result in my image was very identical, only thing I noticed was that the result's borders grew by 1 pixel, not noticeable at all, you will only see it if you zoom maximum (12800%).

---

I know that OP asked for Adobe PS, but since SE is a knowledge website and not a forum, I'm gathering all possible ways of removing white BG from image.

Comment: We don't know if OP has Illustrator or wants to use it. Also I think you got it the other way around: GDSE it's not a forum but a Q&A site, so we should stick to answering what's being asked.

Comment: I literally said "not a forum" I don't know what you're saying.