# Remove outer white space around logo

Tags: adobe-photoshop, logo, shapes, transparency

I currently have a logo with a white puppet inside it. I want to remove the white space around the logo. Because the white space is still "connected" with the inner white puppet I can't manage to get only the outer white space removed. Is there a way to remove only the "outer" white parts of the logo? I tried using the magic wand and lasso tools but I didn't get the desired result. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're in a pinch - use the pen tool in photoshop to trace that arc at the bottom and create a path outside of the blue - doesn't have to be pretty and just contain the white you want removed.
Once created, Command select the path - which should give you the walking ants around the white you want removed.. hit delete

But that is kind of "half-butt" and is only if you cannot get the original logo file - which hopefully is a ai. file. If not you should be able to get the original psd. file[image]

Answer (score 10):

Photoshop is most likely **not** the correct tool to use or the tool you want for a "logo". It would be *much better* to use Illustrator or some other *vector* editing tool.

In any event, assuming you have a raster image layer in Photoshop, if the **Magic Wand** and other selection tools aren't working well for you. You can try using the **Channels** in the image to create a selection. Based on the posted image, it should be an easy thing to create a selection based upon Channels. **[SEE HERE](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/36450/how-would-i-remove-all-the-white-from-this-image-i-just-want-the-image-to-be-th)**.

If you have something *other* than a raster image layer, you'll need to detail the construction. For a Smart Object layer, you would *double-click* the layer to make edits to it.

Answer (score 7):

What you have looks like a logo, but technically, its a poor quality [raster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raster_graphics) file.

Actual logo files do not look like this. You don't see pixels and definitely don't see white corners in properly made logo files.

Forget Photoshop. Install Illustrator. Learn how to rework that in vector format. You can re-build this logo into a proper file in 5 minutes in Illustrator using basic tools.

[image]
[image source](https://www.shutterstock.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/sites/5/2018/02/Vector-vs-Raster_Featured-Image.jpg)

Comment: Very nice your avatar :-)

Comment: -1 There should be brighter blue pixels around the pixelated sun (just kidding)

Answer (score 6):

I still choose Illustrator when I make logos. I 'm showing the solution in Illustrator, then. Note: This is an example.

1. Lock Selection
2. Select Rectangle Tool
3. Make Fill (None)
4. Draw the Path
5. Direct Selection Tool
6. Draw the Path
7. Select Pen Tool
8. Make Anchor Point
9. Delete the Path
10. Select Pen Tool again to join the path
11. Unlock the Object
12. Select both Path and Object
13. Finally, Make a Clipping Mask

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Photoshop is not really the right tool for creating or editing logos.  Sure you could use it if you really have to, but it's less than ideal for such a job because Photoshop only has very limited vector support.

If you don't have access to the original logo file (which should ideally be a vector file), I think the best way to do this would be to recreate the logo in a vector image editor, such as Adobe Illustrator.

You could use the original raster image as a guide. Redraw it with the Pen Tool over the top of the original, then use the Shape builder to make the pieces, and delete the overlaps, Finally fill the pieces of the logo with the colours you want.  At first this may seem quite daunting, however with practice, a job like this would only take a few minutes.

Here's a quick example made in Adobe Illustrator. The original is on the right, vector paths shown top left, final result is bottom left.

[image]